# Android Share Dialog invalid post id

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-share

Hi im using [Facebook Android Share Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android) but After successfully sharing a page on a facebook I get a post id like this: UzpfSTEwMDAwNzU5NjMxNDE5MDoxNjQ0MzI4NjU1ODMwMzI5

I check it via graph api but it still error?

```
 {
   "error": {
   "message": "(#100) This api call does not support permalink tokens",
   "type": "OAuthException",
   "code": 100,
   "fbtrace_id": "B5OJZBt5DRL"
   }
 }
```

Comment: Hi! How do you get post Id properly? Mine always returns null :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post id `UzpfSTEwMDAwNzU5NjMxNDE5MDoxNjQ0MzI4NjU1ODMwMzI5` is encoded to Base64 you should decode it.

Tried to decode it using https://www.base64decode.org/ and I got this `S:_I100007596314190:1644328655830329`. You could do a string manipulation and parse the postId to `100007596314190_1644328655830329`. And you could use it on the Graph API to get the post.

This link should help you http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html in decoding Base64 in Android.

Comment: Please post relevant section within an answer.